# How to remove caption & number from wrapped figure?

Tags: lyx

I have a wrapped non-floating figure fitting within 40% of column width, and I want to remove the caption number and text. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the LyX editing interface?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete it ... Place the cursor directly before the caption and press delete, or just after and press backspace.